# Ошибка Eclipse после обновления Java

Tags: java, eclipse, return, error404

После обновления Java, вылезает такая ошибка от Eclipse

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в виде текста

---

### Eclipse

Java was started but returned exit code=1

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true

-Xms256m

-Xmx2048m

-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10

-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest

-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/-

> http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/

-jar C:\Users\717177\eclipse\java-2020-

03\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar

-os win32

-ws win32

-arch x86_64

-showsplash

C:\Users\717177.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.common_4.15.0.20200313-1200\splash.bmp

-launcher C:\Users\717177\eclipse\java-2020-03\eclipse\eclipse.exe

-name Eclipse

--launcher.library

C:\Users\717177.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426\eclipse_1902.dll

-startup C:\Users\717177\eclipse\java-2020-03\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar

--launcher.appendVmargs

-exitdata 1d7c_124

-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe

-vmargs

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace

-XX:+UseG1GC

-XX:+UseStringDeduplication

-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8

-Dosgi.dataAreaRequiresExplicitInit=true

-Xms256m

-Xmx2048m

-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10

-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest

-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/-

> http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/

-jar C:\Users\717177\eclipse\java-2020-

03\eclipse\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar

[image: версия]

Comment: Вы джаву обновили до какой версии?

Comment: @ArchDemon до 8 версии

Comment: она у вас находится в C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\ ?

Comment: да, в C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java